# SQL Server - Full text Index helpful for what kind of query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What kind of `where` clauses benefits most from full text indexes?

Comment: This sounds a LOT like an exam question.

Comment: Queries that ignore noise words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a couple purely T-SQL queries with a non-SARGable LIKE clause will *almost* * always get an index scan:

```
WHERE comment LIKE '%safety%' -- text that contains the word "safety"
--OR: 
WHERE sometext LIKE '%dog%' -- we want words that begin with "dog"
```

This query, which utilizes a full text index, can get a seek.

```
WHERE CONTAINS(comment, 'safety') 
--OR:
WHERE CONTAINS(someText, 'Dog*')
```

There are many other examples of where FTS will improve the performance in a WHERE clause which you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/query-with-full-text-search).

(*) There are cases where a filtered index or indexed view could allow for a seek.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes won't be beneficial unless you are starting from the left part of the string.  If what you seek does not start with the first character position.  The Index will have zero benefit.

Comment: The OP was asking about full text indexes. What you said is true about your typical clustered or nonclustered index but this is not true about full text indexes.

Comment: There can be some benefit even from an index scan. An index scan will typically require less I/O than a table scan. The smaller the index width relative to the row width the greater the benefit.